# SQL developer returns result while HQL returns error

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm working on a project where i have to generate an HQL query to get thing done in JEE project. My HQL Query is :

```
requete.append("SELECT elec, MIN(tour.datScrutin) dat FROM HbEleElection elec, HbEleTourScrutin tour");
    requete.append(" WHERE elec.idEtaElection <> "+ cstRepository.getIdConstanteByLibelle("ETAT_ELECTION_TERMINEE"));
    requete.append(" AND elec.id = tour.idElection");
    requete.append(" AND elec.zzzDsuEng is null");
    requete.append(" GROUP BY elec.lbcElection");
    requete.append(" ORDER BY dat ");
```

but got nothing as a result.

I managed to clean things and this is the SQL query in my SQL developer returning the results that i want.

```
SELECT elec.lbc_election,
   MIN(tour.dat_Scrutin) dat
FROM Ele_Election elec,
     Ele_Tour_Scrutin tour
WHERE elec.id_Eta_Election <> 335
  AND elec.id_election = tour.id_Election
  AND elec.zzz_Dsu_Eng IS NULL
GROUP BY elec.lbc_Election
ORDER BY dat desc
```

in java with my HQL i got this error for the HQL :

> 1     net.sf.hibernate.QueryException: , expected in SELECT [SELECT elec, MIN(tour.datScrutin) dat FROM vdm.commun.scrutin.dao.hbbean.HbEleElection as elec, vdm.commun.scrutin.dao.hbbean.HbEleTourScrutin tour  WHERE elec.idEtaElection <> 335 AND elec.id = tour.idElection AND elec.zzzDsuEng is null GROUP BY elec.lbcElection ORDER BY dat ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed 'elec.lbc_election' and trying  to select Bean name that's why error is coming.just try this query

```
requete.append("SELECT elec.lbc_election, MIN(tour.datScrutin) as dat FROM HbEleElection elec, HbEleTourScrutin tour"); requete.append(" WHERE elec.idEtaElection <> "+ cstRepository.getIdConstanteByLibelle("ETAT_ELECTION_TERMINEE")); requete.append(" AND elec.id = tour.idElection"); requete.append(" AND elec.zzzDsuEng is null"); requete.append(" GROUP BY elec.lbcElection"); requete.append(" ORDER BY dat ");
```